# Invalid prop type when using CSSTransition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with `CSSTranstion` for React. I am using this to animate mobile menu for my small app. All was working good before I decided to add react-transition-group pack, where I am using `<CSSTransition />`.

I have my navbar element:

```
render() {
    const { navItems, isOpen } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <NavBar navLinks={navItems} />
        <button onClick={this.openDrawer} className='Navigation-btn'>
          <span />
          <span />
          <span />
        </button>
        {isOpen && <BackDrop onClick={this.closeDrawer} />}
        <SideDrawer onClick={this.closeDrawer} show={isOpen}>
          <MobileNav navLinks={navItems} />
        </SideDrawer>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

This is class component where I have my `navLinks` items. I am passing those to my functional components. One is `MobileNav`:

```
<nav className='Navigation__Mobile'>
      <ul>
        {navLinks.map((link) => {
          return (
            <li key={link.id}>
              <NavLink
                exact
                key={link.id}
                to={link.to}
                className={link.className}>
                {link.name}
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Here I am rendering my `navLinks` items. Nothing super fancy here.
I am using `SideDrawer` component, where I am "keeping" my mobile navigation and where I am using `CSSTransition`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

import './SideDrawer.scss';

const SideDrawer = ({ children, show, onClick }) => {
  const content = (
    <CSSTransition
      in={show}
      timeout={200}
      classNames='slide-in-right'
      mountOnEnter
      unmountOnExit>
      <aside onClick={onClick} className='SideDrawer'>
        {children}
      </aside>
      ;
    </CSSTransition>
  );

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    content,
    document.getElementById('drawer-portal')
  );
};

SideDrawer.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  show: PropTypes.bool,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

I have two errors here:

1. `` Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Transition` ``
2. `React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.`

I am digging this from some time, but nothing is working. I think I am returning one element, as `children` prop was working okay before adding `CSSTransition`.

Comment: You've got a `;` after `</aside>`. Looks like a typo and adds an extra child to `CSSTransition`. Remove it and see if it fixes the errors.

Comment: good catch. Thanks this is working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a `;` after `</aside>`. Looks like a typo and adds an extra child to `CSSTransition`. Remove it and see if it fixes the errors.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how this got there :)